# Spring AMQP send & receive with temporary queues using a noLocal consumer

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit, qpid

When sending and receiving using temporary queues a consumer is created with the `noLocal` attribute set to `true` (see [`RabbitTemplate#doSendAndReceiveWithTemporary` method line 1297 of version 1.7.4.RELEASE](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/blob/1.7.x/spring-rabbit/src/main/java/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/core/RabbitTemplate.java#L1297)).

According to the [javadocs for the `basicConsume` method](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-java-client/blob/4.0.x-stable/src/main/java/com/rabbitmq/client/Channel.java#L875), when this property is set to `true`, then *"the server should not deliver to this consumer messages published on this channel's connection"*.

Now, from what I can tell, this consumer is being set up to actually receive the reply message. If I am correct, then shouldn't the reply **not** be received at all due to the `noLocal` property being set to `true`?

When using RabbitMQ as the AMQP broker, reply messages are being received just fine. However, when using Apache Qpid, the reply is not received. In fact, it is only received when the `noLocal` property is set to `false`.

Comment: After some more research I came across this article (https://www.rabbitmq.com/interoperability.html#qpid-python-tests) which points out that no-local consumers are not supported by RabbitMQ. Nonetheless, the question still stands, if it were supported by RabbitMQ, then should the reply be received?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unusual to have the server side running in the same application as the client side. That's the only way no-local should affect this scenario since, normally, the client-side doesn't publish the reply.

We don't claim compatibility with QPID (certainly not AMQP 1.0) but I see QPID claims support for AMQP 0.9.x so feel free to open a [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP) and we'll take a look as time permits.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This actually happened during a spring boot test which makes use of qpid as an embedded amqp broker. So in my case I have both the server and the client running within the same app. I’ve already opened a github issue (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/issues/712). Would this be enough?